# Submitting form in partial view calls wrong controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action, partial-views

I have a partial view and the corresponding controller which looks as follows:

```
public class SearcherController : Controller
{
    SearcherViewModel searcherVM;
    //
    // GET: /Searcher/
    public PartialViewResult Index()
    {
        searcherVM = new SearcherViewModel();
        return PartialView("_SearcherPartial", searcherVM);
    }

    public ViewResult Search(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

On the master page I render the partial view as follows:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index","Searcher");}
```

In my partial view I have a form with some inputs. Form SHOULD call Search action in the Searcher controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Searcher"))
{
...some inputs
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" />
}
```

However when I click on the "SEARCH" button, the "Index" action of the SearchController is called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. When I tested it is the Search action that was called. You must be missing something from your question. Can you provide a full example allowing to reproduce the problem?

Comment: hmm..I don't know what else can I provide

Comment: no matter what kind of form is provided, always default action (index) from a SearcherController is called

Comment: _SearcherPartial is in Shared folder. Maybe this is the case?

Comment: What does the form's action attribute has when you do a page view source?

Comment: POST should be the method attribute, not the action attribute.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, it's as follows: Html.BeginForm("Search", "Searcher"). I figured out that when I have 2 forms on the page, submitting first calls default action(index) and the second one calls Search action